# Iam trying to find auto EMA Length , which can equal to high of 40 bar ago

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Iam trying to create a ema with auto Length based on high of 40 bar ago ,
have tried to modified and stuck now, because it always result autolen = 500 , that mean always plot ema(close,500)
hope someone can help me.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Skrip saya",overlay = true)





ema(src, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? src : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])




autolen = 0
for i = 1 to 500
    // Condition to check if ema[40]==high[40]
    if ema(close, autolen)[40] == high[40]
        break
    autolen := autolen + 1

plot(ema(close,autolen))
```

Comment: `ema[40]==high[40]` this is very unlikely to happen. Can you show us an example when this is the case?

Comment: yes , that why always return autolen = 500 , i should use "nearest to" than "equal"